# Clear all active sessions for a user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, session-cookies, logout

Here, I don’t have a session cookie. I know only the user id of the user I want to clear all active sessions for.
Currently, I am going through each session in the sessions table and checking `warden.user.user.key` attribute. If it is equal to that user id I am destroying this session.
This works fine but the sessions table contains more than a million records. Is there an optimized way to do so?